# Training loss stays constant while validation loss fluctuates heavily

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

While doing transfer learning on VGG, with decent amount of data, and with the following configuration:

```
base_big_3 = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=[IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3])

model_big_3 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_big_3.add(base_big_3)
model_big_3.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model_big_3.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model_big_3.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model_big_3.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=['acc'])

history = model_big_3.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=BATCH_SIZE,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=valid_generator,
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
      )
```

The training loss and validation loss varies as below, wherein the training loss is constant throughout and validation loss spikes initially to become constant afterwards:

[image: loss graph]

**What I tried out**

1. I tried the solutions given [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19578/why-my-training-and-validation-loss-is-not-changing) one by one and decreased the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.0001.Now, this time training loss did go down slightly but then validation error still seems super fluctuating. The training loss and validation loss varies as below:

[image: loss curve]

2. The above solution link also suggests to normalize the input, but in my opinion images doesn't need to be normalized because the data doesn't vary much and also that the VGG network already has batch normalization, please correct me if I'm wrong.Please point what is leading to this kind of behavior, what to change in the configs and how can I improve training?

Comment: It is expected to see the validation loss fluctuate more as the train loss as shown in your second example. You could try using regularization such as dropout to stabilize the validation loss.

Comment: We *always* normalize the input data, and batch normalization is irrelevant to that

Comment: volatility of loss strongly depending on the data size. I think that your validation_data size is too small. Normally I use 5000 samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I see is you set steps_per_epoch = BATCH_SIZE. Assume you have 3200 training samples and the BATCH_SIZE=32. To go through all your training samples you would have to go through 3200/32=100 batches. But with steps_per_epoch=BATCH_SIZE=32 you only go through 1024 samples in an epoch. Set the steps_per_epoch as

```
steps_per_epoch =number_of_train samples//BATCH_SIZE
```

where BATCH_SIZE is whatever you specified in the generator. Alternatively you can leave it as None and model.fit will determine the right value internally.
As stated in the model.fit documentation located [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) ,

```
Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets,
generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).
```

Since in model.fit you use train_generator I assume this is a generator.
The VGG model was trained on imagenet images where the pixel values were rescaled  within the range from -1 to +1. So somewhere in your input pipeline you should rescale the images. For example image=image/127.5-1 will do the job. What BATCH_SIZE did you use? Making it larger (within the limits of your memory size) may help smooth out the fluctuations.
I also recommend you use two keras callbacks, EarlyStopping and ReduceLROnPlateau.  Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) Set them up to monitor validation loss. My suggested code is shown below

```
estop=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",patience=4,verbose=1,   
                                      restore_best_weights=True)
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5,
                                       patience=2, verbose=1)
callbacks=[estop, rlronp]    
# in model.fit add callbacks=callbacks
```